# Is it possible to receive virtual input from the portal in the HoloLens 2 when it is configured in Kiosk mode

Tags: hololens, portal, kiosk-mode

I want to run my App in Kiosk mode to prevent users from accidentally launching the home menu with the bloom hand gesture. I would also like to be able to remotely control the App from the portal. When the HL2 is in Kiosk mode, my code to read remote input seems to stop working? Is it possible to have both Kiosk mode and remote input? If so, how?

Otherwise, are there any ways to prevent tracking the bloom gesture. If I cover the sensors, I get an environment mapping popup augmentation. Disabling environment mapping would be an alternative solution for me but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to receive virtual input from the portal in HoloLens 2 when it is configured in Kiosk mode

The virtual input feature should work in Kiosk mode, we verified with the Microsoft Map App and the input textbox of the active app can receive the data as expected. The device OS Build we tested is 20348.1432.

> are there any ways to prevent tracking the bloom gesture.

I think what you are talking about is the Start gesture, the bloom gesture only works on the HoloLens 1 and is no more available on Hololens2. On HoloLens 2, the Start gesture is to tap the Start icon that appears on your wrist.

To disable the Start menu, there are two supported scenarios included in the Kiosk mode, by enabling Single app mode, your device will launch the specified single app automatically, and no start menu is displayed. For more information, please refer to this link:[Set up HoloLens as a kiosk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-kiosk?tabs=uisak%2Cnonaadlogon)

Comment: Thank you. In order to receive virtual input into my app from the web portal I had to add a touch screen keyboard into the scene. Is there another way of receiving virtual input?

Comment: You can add the InputField to your scene with the right-click menu in the Hierarchy window, without any code.

Comment: I just tried this. InputFields don't seem to receive remote input form the HL2 web portal.

Comment: Could you try to deploy the MixedRealityKeyboardExample scene which is located at Assets/MRTK/Examples/Experimental/MixedRealityKeyboard/Scenes? We verified it can work in our device.